# How to store ip address into variable and pass it to shell command?

Tags: php, html, shell

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$mac=shell_exec('arp-a'.'$ip')
echo $mac;
```

i wanted to take a take ip address of the machine and pass it to the shell command it is working well if i provide the ipaddress manually but through variable it is not working.Working well if ip is provided manually eg.:$mac=shell_exec('arp -a 192.168.0.32');

Comment: How are you executing the script?

Comment: What result do you expect?

Comment: Which platform are you on?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot spaces:

```
$mac=shell_exec('arp-a'.'$ip')
                    ^-^--here
```

So the command you're executing is actually

```
arp-a127.0.0.1
```

instead of

```
arp -a 127.0.0.1
```

And note that `'` doesn't interpolate variables, so you're passing a literal `$`, `i`, `p` chracters to the shell. You do NOT need quotes at all:

```
$mac = shell_exec('arp -a ' . $ip);
```

Comment: then don't use `shell_exec()`. use [exec()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and capture both the output and exit status to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

Your $ip is in quotes so you pass an actual "$ip" literal to the shell.

try this

```
$mac=shell_exec('arp-a '.$ip)
```